# What exactly do letterspace change?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, letterspacing

All major engines (pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX) support letterspacing, except the original TeX of course. LaTeX users can access letterspacing via higher interface. For example, the `microtype` package (pdfLaTeX) and the `fontspec` package (XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX).

**But what exactly do letterspace change?** Also, the changes seem to be engine-dependent: pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX are doing their own things.

---

To illustrate, I will use an example under XeTeX. On the primitive level, letterspacing is added by specifying a numerical value to the `letterspace` key:

```
\font\1="[texgyretermes-regular.otf]" at 10pt % no letterspace
\font\2="[texgyretermes-regular.otf]:letterspace=5" at 10pt % add 5% em of letterspace
```

(`fontspec` users will do something like `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[LetterSpace=5]`)

Given a word (a consecutive run of glyphs), XeTeX will insert letterspace between glyphs *within* the word (while respecting kerning and ligatures), but will not insert letterspace on the two boundaries (the two ends of that word). However, XeTeX will also *change* the width of a regular space, so that the glue item between words is increased by the letterspace amount (the natural width component is increased by this amount, to be more precise). Consider the following text string `VAT fire`:

```
On input:
  <char V> <char A> <char T> <space> <char f> <char i> <char r> <char e>

Rendered via font and XeTeX:
  <glyph V> <implicit kern> <glyph A> <implicit kern> <glyph T>
  <glue with natural width, stretch, and shrink>
  <glyph ligature f_i> <glyph r> <glyph e>

What do letterspace change?
  <glyph V> <implicit kern> <glyph A> <implicit kern> <glyph T>
                   ↑                         ↑
               add 5% em                 add 5% em
  <glue with natural width, stretch, and shrink>
                   ↑           ↑           ↑
               add 5% em, and proportionally here
  <glyph ligature f_i> <glyph r> <glyph e>
                      ↑         ↑
                  add 5% em, and here
```

But if we think of space as a character/glyph not a glue, adding twice the amount of letterspace to space makes more sense, right?

```
Should space get one extra letterspace amount, or twice the amount?
  ... <glyph T> <space> <glyph ligature f_i> ...
                   ↑
               add 5% em
versus
  ... <glyph T> <space> <glyph ligature f_i> ...
               ↑       ↑
           add 5% em, and here
```

Here is the plain-XeTeX code to support my observation

```
\font\1="[texgyretermes-regular.otf]" at 10pt % no letterspace
\font\2="[texgyretermes-regular.otf]:letterspace=5" at 10pt % add 5% em of letterspace

\hbox{\1VAT fire (no letterspace)}
\hbox{\2VAT fire\1 (add 5\%\,em letterspace)}

% The effect of letterspace on words (glyph runs)
\setbox0\hbox{\1fire}
\setbox2\hbox{\2fire}
\hbox{\1\unhcopy2 \ is wider than \unhcopy0,
\the\numexpr(\wd2-\wd0)*100/\dimexpr1em\relax\relax\%\,em wider;
since there are two spots to add letterspace.}

% The effect of letterspace on space
\setbox0\hbox{\1 }
\setbox2\hbox{\2 }
\hbox{\1\vrule\unhcopy2\vrule\ is wider than \vrule\unhcopy0\vrule,
\the\numexpr(\wd2-\wd0)*100/\dimexpr1em\relax\relax\%\,em wider.}

\bye
```

[image: letterspace]

---

For LuaTeX (which I’m not familiar with), users access fonts through `luaotfload`. Prior to `luaotfload v2.96`, letterspace does *not* change the width of word space. After `luaotfload v2.96`, letterspace changes the word space:

> This is consistent with the XeTeX behaviour (and the amount of stretching should be similar). —*§ kernfactor & letterspace, luaotfload documentation*

Comment: just a quick comment: `microtype` (which also works with `luatex`, but not (yet) with `xetex`) allows adjusting all of these aspects (inner spacing, outer spacing, outer kerning).